# java 2d memory address

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

in java if we have:

```
int[][] x = new int[3][3];
```

the memory address of x is different from the memory address of x[0].  As  x[0] gives the memory address of the first column.  So the memory address of x[0][0] is different than the memory address of x[0].

are there any computer languages that store a 2d array as a matrix and not as an array of arrays?

would the address of x always be different from x[0] and the address of x[0] equal x[0][0]?

Comment: I am curious: who do you determine the memory address of `x` and `x[0]`?

Comment: Well, there's C and C++.  But I'm curious like Turing85 - how are you getting memory addresses?  Java is supposed to shield you from stuff like that.  Unless you mean hash codes, of course, which are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: do you mean who or how?  Isn't the toString() method "close  enough for government work" a reasonable surrogate for the address

Comment: but c stores 2d arrays as an array of arrays

Comment: No, the C compiler acts as if the 2D array is an array of arrays.  Under the covers, it's stored as a matrix.  And no, `toString()` does NOT return a memory address.

Comment: i know toString does not return the actual memory address but it's really not important  I thought the hash code would be close enough i.e if two elements have the same address won't they almost always have the same hash code?

Comment: @DCR The [`toString()`-method of `Object`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l237) prints out the `hashCode()` of the object. And the [`hashCode()` of `Object`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l92) is "*typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer*".

Comment: right, so if two objects have the same address won't the hash code usually be the same?

Comment: I thought in C if we declare int[][] x = new int[3][3]; we can access x with x{2][2] or x[8] would give us the same cell but, clearly you can't do that in Java

Comment: Because of the way memory works, each index would always have their own memory address. Memory is linear so you can't very well store something two-dimensional in it without creating a linear representation for it. The structure of an array in memory is simply the number of entries followed by the entries themselves. In a 2d array, these entries are simply more arrays. When you access an index, it takes that index * the size of each item to get the offset, then adds the offset to the original pointer to get the pointer of the item. I don't think there's any other performant way to do this.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  Doesn't java and c store 2d arrays differently?  Specifically, in c  2d array will be stored sequentially while in java it won't.  In c I would need to create an array of pointers and then with malloc allocate memory for the columns to duplicate what happens in java

Comment: As far as I know, in Java, If two objects have the same memory address, they are the same object. One is an alias of the other. Java doesn't have something like the `EQUIVALENCE` of  Fortran or the `union` of C / C++.  Also, if two different objects, `a`, and `b` return `true` for `a.equals(b)`, they are supposed to return the same value for `hashCode ()`.

Comment: I believe @DCR is correct, at least in regards to Java.  In Java, arrays are reference types. Suppose I have `int [][] foo = new int [20][15]; int [] bar = new int [12];`.  Each row of `foo` is a reference to an `int []`.   An entire row can be replaced by changing the reference to that row:  `foo [9] = bar;`  Note that Java 2D arrays can be "ragged" (have rows of different lengths). In this example, `foo` becomes ragged from  `foo [9] = bar;` being executed.

Comment: By the way, in a C++ course, one assignment was to create a `class` that represented a edges of a graph using an adjacency matrix. Because the graph was undirected, the professor encouraged us to use a "triangular" array. If the graph had `n` nodes (vertices), row 0 would have `n` columns. Row 1 would have `n - 1` columns. Row 2 would have `n - 2` columns.  Row 3 ... . If my memory is correct, we coded the array pretty much the same as it would be done in Java. It was an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> are there any computer languages that store a 2d array as a matrix and
> not as an array of arrays?

Yes. Or, at least, there used to be.

There is the possibility of using an assembler language, where the programmer has extreme control over how arrays might be handled. But, let's assume the question is about high-level languages (>=3GL).

I don't know about modern version of Fortran, but the early versions of FORTRAN stored any array, including multi-dimensional arrays, in consecutive storage locations. So, for example, if you  declared an array as `INTEGER FOO (3,4,5)`, then `FOO` and `FOO (1,1,1)` would have the same memory address.  `FOO` would occupy a block of 60 `INTEGER` sized locations. The compiler generates code to find, from the subscript values, the location of an element in a manner similar to what @Jesse described in a comment on the question. It's slightly different to allow for the fact that FORTRAN subscripts started at one instead of zero.

By the way, FORTRAN subscript are in opposite order of most other languages. In Java, C, C++, and COBOL, the major subscripts are to the left. In FORTRAN, they were to the right.

FORTRAN syntax didn't allow missing subscripts. So, continuing the example, something like `FOO (2,3)` would generate a compiler error.

Now, suppose there was the following method:

```
      REAL FUNCTION MEAN (ARR, N)
      INTEGER N, ARR (N)
      REAL SUM
      DO 400 I = 1,N,1
      SUM = SUM + ARR (I)
  400 CONTINUE   
      RETURN SUM / N
      END
```

A programmer could it use to calculate the mean of the entire `FOO` array, or any part of it:

```
     REAL ALLMEAN, LEVEL3MEAN, ROWMEAN

     ALLMEAN = MEAN (FOO(1,1,1), 60)
     LEVEL3MEAN = MEAN (FOO(1,1,3), 12)
     ROWMEAN = MEAN (FOO(1,2,3), 4)
```

Suppose, for some strange reason, there was this:

```
      AVGPART = MEAN (FOO (2,3,2), 20)
```

This would use 20 consecutive elements of `FOO`, even if those elements were in different rows or levels.

When I took a C++ course, someone didn't like having to type separate `[x]` subscripts for multidimensional arrays. Instead of `foo [2][1][0]`, he would rather type something like `foo.get (2,1,0)`, so wrote a convenience wrapper class for an array. Such code might still have `foo [t][r][c]` inside the wrapper class. Or, it could allocate a 1D array. Once the class was created, it allowed him to specify subscripts as arguments in a call to a method.

Code in Java to do that, using the 1D array option, might look like this:

```
  public class Block {
     // class for regular 3D Array
     private int [] array;
     private int rows, int columns, int levels;
 
     public Block (int t, int r, int c) { 
         rows = r;
         columns = c;
         levels = t;
         array = new array [ t * r * c];
    }

    public int get (int t, int r, int c) { 
       return array [ t * rows * columns + r * columns + c ];  
    }
    
    public void set (int value, int t, int r, int c) { 
       array [ t * rows * columns + r * columns + c ] = value;
    }
    ...
 }
```